# How can I construct a 4x4 rotation matrix to look in the direction of a 4 dimensional vector?

Tags: rotation, matrix-multiplication

How can I construct a 4x4 rotation matrix to look in the direction of a 4d vectors?

I have two 4d vectors, representing points in four dimensional space, and I need to rotate an object to point from one to the other.

Every solution to similar problems that I've seen only works in three space.

Ideally I would like an efficient solution, as this operation will need to be done every frame, possibly for multiple objects in my game. The project is in the Unity3d engine, and I'm scripting in c#, in case that's relevant.

Comment: This question has little relevance to programming per se. You should ask on math.se.

Comment: I'm trying to program a camera to follow an object in 4d space. Understanding the math would help me figure out how to program it, but there might also be an easy way to program it without going in depth into the math.